# Sql Oderconflict

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I try to create a view. I have 2 Tables like

```
ID | FileName  | PathId
----------------------
1  | Setup.exe | 2
2  | Test.doc  | 1


ID | Path      | 
----------------
1  | C:\\      | 
2  | D:\\      |
```

Id like to merge both tables the following way

```
 ID | FileName  | Path |Combined
 ----------------------
 1  | Setup.exe | D:\\ | D:\\Setup.exe
 2  | Test.doc  | c:\\ | C.\\Text.Doc
```

My try looks the following way:

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.Files.FileName, dbo.Files.PathId, dbo.Paths.Path, dbo.Paths.Path + dbo.Files.FileName AS Combined 
FROM         dbo.Files INNER JOIN dbo.Paths
 ON dbo.Files.PathID = dbo.Paths.ID
ORDER BY dbo.Files.FileName, dbo.Files.PathId, dbo.Paths.Path, Combined
```

This is not workign cause the Sqlserver aborts with the errormesseage that there is an "Orderconflict for the 4th column of the ODER BY-term".

Can somebody help me and tell me what am i doing wrong?
Thnaks in advance.

Comment: There is no column `Combined` instead put existing columns `dbo.Paths.Path, dbo.Files.FileName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.Files.FileName, dbo.Files.PathId, dbo.Paths.Path, dbo.Paths.Path + dbo.Files.FileName AS Combined 
FROM         dbo.Files INNER JOIN dbo.Paths
 ON dbo.Files.PathID = dbo.Paths.ID
ORDER BY dbo.Files.FileName, dbo.Files.PathId, dbo.Paths.Path, (dbo.Paths.Path + dbo.Files.FileName );
```

"Combined" is an assigned variable(alias) that will not be recognized in this scope. Where as, in the below query, it would work since the variable "Combined" will fall within the scope.

```
SELECT FILENAME, PATHID, PATH, COMBINED FROM 
(
  SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.Files.FileName, dbo.Files.PathId, dbo.Paths.Path, dbo.Paths.Path + dbo.Files.FileName AS Combined 
  FROM         dbo.Files INNER JOIN dbo.Paths
   ON dbo.Files.PathID = dbo.Paths.ID
  ORDER BY dbo.Files.FileName, dbo.Files.PathId, dbo.Paths.Path, (dbo.Paths.Path + dbo.Files.FileName );
) ORDER BY FILENAME, PATHID, PATH, COMBINED
```

Comment: However, since filename and path is already there in orderby condition, is the (Path + Filename) required in order by?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an alias in the order by statement. SQL Server didn't know yet that the Combined is actually the dbo.Paths.Path + dbo.Files.FileName. If you want to order by the value COmbined you need to write the tables columns or use an common table expression and then sort by your new columns.

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.Files.FileName, dbo.Files.PathId, dbo.Paths.Path, dbo.Paths.Path + dbo.Files.FileName AS Combined 
FROM         dbo.Files INNER JOIN dbo.Paths
 ON dbo.Files.PathID = dbo.Paths.ID
ORDER BY dbo.Files.FileName, dbo.Files.PathId, dbo.Paths.Path, (dbo.Paths.Path + dbo.Files.FileName)
```

or

```
with cte as 
(
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.Files.FileName, dbo.Files.PathId, dbo.Paths.Path, dbo.Paths.Path + dbo.Files.FileName AS Combined 
FROM         dbo.Files INNER JOIN dbo.Paths
 ON dbo.Files.PathID = dbo.Paths.ID
ORDER BY dbo.Files.FileName, dbo.Files.PathId, dbo.Paths.Path, (dbo.Paths.Path + dbo.Files.FileName)
)
ORDER BY FileName, PathId, Path, Combined
```